# In WSL, VS Code intellisense can't resolve c++ lib includes in .h header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, header-files

I can't figure out how to fix this annoying intellisense problem. Everything compiles just fine though. If i change the extension to .hpp everything is ok, but with .h it just can't find any c++ standart libraries.

All i have is test.h file with `#include <iostream>` in it. . I've added `"/usr/include", "/usr/local/include"` to both include and browse path but it didn't change anything.

Error:

`#include errors detected. Consider updating your compile_commands.json or includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/mnt/c/dev/opengl_cmake/src/shader/test.h).C/C++(1696) cannot open source file "iostream"C/C++(1696)`

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliSense of your VS Code might have the wrong settings or miss the settings completely.

Try `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and Select `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` and expand the Advanced Settings Menu. Check if the `Configuration provider` is properly configured with the right config info (e.g. `ms-vscode.cmake-tools`).

After changing the `Configuration provider`, you can double check the settings json file to make sure the correct configuration has been populated to the VS Code settings json. And then try use the intellisense again with the source files you have.

[image: VS Code Settings JSON]